# Count records with sub query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables and I am trying to figure out how to make a sub query work to get a row count included.  My tables are named in a way which will not make sense so I will present a simple example:

```
Table 1: country
columns:
country_id
country_name

Table 2: actors
columns:
country_id
actor_name
```

Ideally I would like to return:

```
results
country_name, actor_name, actor_count_country
USA, Denzil Washington, 3
USA, The Rock, 3
USA, Tom Hanks, 3
Australia, Nicole Kidman, 2
Australia, Russel Crow, 2
```

How would I write a query which lists all the actors, but also provides a count of the actors in each country like the above example?

Answer (score 0):

You can get it by simple aggregation function `count`.

You'd better add an `index` in country_name and actor_name.

```
SELECT
  c.country_name,
  a.actor_name,
  COUNT (c.country_id) AS actor_count_country
FROM
  country c
  INNER JOIN actors a
    ON a.country_id = c.country_id
GROUP BY c.country_name,
  a.actor_name
```

Comment: Your country count is running 1 each time. Please see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=97d22b9ecbcb1cd3da5b85f2567584d6

Answer (score 0):

If your version supports it  we can use `COUNT(~) OVER (PARTITION BY ~)` to get the total number of actors.
Otherwise we can use a sub-query. I give an example of each method.

> ```
> SELECT
>   c.country_name,
>   a.actor_name,
>   COUNT(a.actor_name) OVER
>     (PARTITION BY c.country_name)
>     AS actor_count_country
> FROM
>   country c
>   JOIN actors a
>     ON a.country_id = c.country_id
> GROUP BY c.country_name,
>   a.actor_name
> ```
>
> ```
> country_name | actor_name        | actor_count_country
> :----------- | :---------------- | ------------------:
> Australia    | Nicole Kidman     |                   2
> Australia    | Russel Crow       |                   2
> USA          | Denzil Washington |                   3
> USA          | The Rock          |                   3
> USA          | Tom Hanks         |                   3
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
>   c.country_name,
>   a.actor_name,
>   t.actor_count_country
> FROM
>   country c
> JOIN actors a
>  ON a.country_id = c.country_id
> JOIN (
>   SELECT 
>     country_id,
>     SUM(country_id) 
>     AS actor_count_country
>     FROM country
>     GROUP BY country_id
>   ) as t
>  ON a.country_id = t.country_id
>  ;
> ```
>
> ```
> country_name | actor_name        | actor_count_country
> :----------- | :---------------- | ------------------:
> USA          | Denzil Washington |                   1
> USA          | The Rock          |                   1
> USA          | Tom Hanks         |                   1
> Australia    | Nicole Kidman     |                   2
> Australia    | Russel Crow       |                   2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=63563a34f2544570712217e35e15413d)*